# SENDER ID in Asterisk send gsm SMS

Tags: sms, asterisk

i'm new to asterisk,i wanted to send an SMS using the command

`Action: smscommand command: gsm send sms $port+1 $destination "$message" $id`

and i did it, the message reach to destination successfully.

What i'm trying now to achieve : is to add a SENDER ID , but by looking into the docs i didn't found any way to do that using the command **gsm send sms**

any help please !!
thanks in advance

[here is what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaj7S.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send text id or short number if you are using usual sim card and gsm gate. Your gsm provider network will not accept any id, it will be selected based on your sim info.

If you need that, you need digital connection via SMSC or third-party sms gate connected via SMSC.

Comment: Thank you very much .... can u provide any links to help , because i tried to google it but since i'm new i didn't get much